# 'Object already attached to session' and 'no such table'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm struggling with SQLAlchemy and py.test.

In my `__init__.py` I create a engine and a session using:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

I also have a `entity.py` and a `test_entity.py`. In both files I import `session`

```
from __init__ import session
```

In `conftest.py` I defined a function which sets up the database and create a schema from `Base.metadata`.

The point is that all transactions inside my test module all pass, but all transactions in my class being tested fails with errors like `Object already bound to session` (when adding and commiting an object) or with `OperationalError: no such table` (when fetching an object).

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found out that all works fine when I use a database on disk.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////path/to/db')
```

It is [documented](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior):

> Pysqlite’s default behavior is to prohibit the usage of a single
>   connection in more than one thread. [...] Pysqlite does include a
>   now-undocumented flag known as check_same_thread which will disable
>   this check, however note that pysqlite connections are still not safe
>   to use in concurrently in multiple threads.